# How to disable thunderbird shortcut

Tags: shortcut, thunderbird

i use both thunderbird and zend.
ctrl+shift+r is used by them.
but when i use it in zend and other places, i found that it is a global shortcut of thunderbird.

does any one know how to disable the shortcuts or it's just a bug for me only?

Answer (score 2):

You can install [keyconfig](http://mozilla.dorando.at/readme.html) and deactivate the shortcut.

Comment: It is a bit hard to find how to install keyconfig, here I described it: http://superuser.com/a/823349/160420